Tight upper bound on the function of expected value
Let $R$ be a positive integer, $\mathcal{X}$ be the sample space and $x \in \mathcal{X}$ be an event of the sample space; $P(x)$ denotes the probability of occurrence of event $x$. The problem is to upper bound the following expression:
$$
\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}x(P(x))^{\frac{1}{R}},
$$
in terms of $$\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}xP(x).$$
Is it possible to get a tighter bound for the expression?

is $\mathcal X$ finite ?

Yes, $\mathcal{X}$ is finite.

Bound in terms of what?  If it's to depend on $P$ or the $x,$ then please state how, for otherwise the question is too indefinite.  In any event we need you to stipulate conditions on the values of the $x.$ For instance, if they are all nonpositive, then trivially $0 = 0\times E[x]$ is a universal upper bound.

An upper bound is $\sum\limits_{x\gt 0} x$

I don't know how if that is sufficient for your needs, but the first idea that comes to mind, assuming $x\ge 0$, is to write  $x=x^{1/R}\cdot x^{1-1/R} $ so that by Hölder's inequality with $p\equiv R$ and $q\equiv (1- 1/R)^{-1}=R/(R-1)$ :
\begin{align}
\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}x(P(x))^{1/R} &= \sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}(xP(x))^{1/R}x^{1-1/R}\\
&\le \left(\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}xP(x)\right)^{1/R}\cdot\left(\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}x\right)^{1 -1/R} 
\end{align}

I know this doesn't work for negative values of $x$ that's why i wrote "assuming $x\ge 0$". OP did not specify so I simply gave a simple condition under which an upper bound can be obtained.

I used the inequality in the form
$$\sum x_k y_k \le \left(\sum x_k^p\right)^{1/p}\cdot \left(\sum y_k^q\right)^{1/q}$$
for $x_k \equiv (xP(x))^{1/R}$, $y_k\equiv x^{1-1/R}$, $p\equiv R$ and $q\equiv (1-1/R)^{-1}$... did i get it wrong ?

Thanks for bearing with me: that clears it up. (+1).
